# Zurb - What is the purpose of the adjust-pip function?

Tags: zurb-foundation

https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/js/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js

Foundation.libs.dropdown.adjust_pip - what does "pip" stand for?  Is it the little triangle pointer? Triangle positioning is the job of the adjust_pip function?  Those calculations seem to be killing performance when the dropdown content is "long" down the page... especially on mobile.  Profiling with F12 tools indicates **heavy** layout thrashing.

Comment: Yup, its the triangle pointer positioning.  Our solution is to just kill the adjust_pip function like this: Foundation.libs.dropdown.adjust_pip = function() {};  We are not using the pip (not visible)... and live with the consequence of all Zurb dropdowns on the page... not have/support pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes pip is that drop down triangle pointer, found lots of references to it in the Foundation documentation for [Dropdown buttons](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown_buttons.html).

That js file you rightly point out has a lot of calculations based on different scenarios it's checking for.

Foundation is a great framework, but I don't recommend using much of their javascript. For example, [they even advise to not use their Orbit slider and its development has been deprecated](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/14504-moving-on-from-developing-orbit). However their smaller modules like Reveal (lightbox) are excellent.